# Is a holomorphic function on a subvariety of $\mathbb C^n$ locally a restriction?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Suppose that $X\subset \mathbb C^n$ is a subvariety (locally given by holomorphic equations) and $f: X\to \mathbb C$ is a function. Suppose that $f$ is

1) continuous,

2) holomorphic on the smooth part of $X$.

Is it true that for any $x\in X$ there exists an open subset $x\in U\subset \mathbb C^n$ and a holomorphic function $F: U\to \mathbb C$ such that $f|_{U\cap X} = F|_{U\cap X}$?

If not, will it be true if in addition $X$ is locally irreducible?

Comment: I think X would be called an analytic subspace rather than a subvariety.

Comment: Consider the variety X; y^2=x^3 in C^2 and the function y/x restricted to X . If X has normal singularities what you hope for is true.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Can you explain (or give a reference) why what I hope is true if $X$ has normal singularities?

Comment: @Mikhail I believe Mohan’s comment is an exercise in Hartshorne.

Comment: @Mikhail : One needs to talk of X with a sheaf of holomorphic functions. The pair (X,O_X )s normal then f is automatically holomorphic and therefore has local extension . See Grauert Remmert Coherent analytic sheaves page 144. For f to be holomorphic we only need the pair (X,O_X) to be seminormal see Grauert Several Complex Variables vol 7 page 92 .